# How do you use _get_wpgmptr?

Tags: visual-c++

I have this:

```
wchar_t *executable_path;
_get_wpgmptr(&executable_path);
```

which crashes the application. What should I do instead? I don't think I need to initialize the string, but that didn't work anyway.

This doesn't crash

```
wchar_t *executable_path;
executable_path  = _wpgmptr;
```

but it's deprecated and also

```
lstrlenW(executable_path)
```

returns 0 instead of the length of the path.

Comment: [`Only call _get_wpgmptr if your program has a wide entry point, like wmain() or wWinMain().`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/get-wpgmptr?view=msvc-170) do you have a wide entry point?

Comment: @tkausl. I don't know but `_get_pgmptr` works so I guess not.

Comment: Then use this function instead.

Comment: `_get_pgmptr` doesn't correctly return paths with non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Then give your program a wide entry point, like `wmain` or `wWinMain`.

Answer (score 0):

Program has main() or WinMain() entry point instead of a wide entry point wmain() or wWinMain().

[Only call _get_wpgmptr if your program has a wide entry point, like wmain() or wWinMain().](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/get-wpgmptr?view=msvc-170)

I'm using `GetModuleFileNameW()` instead which returns the unicode path even without a wide entry point. You have call it iteratively and adjust the buffer size until it's big enough.